# openpyxl read formula value without changing formula

Tags: python-3.x, excel-formula, openpyxl

I want to read the formula value in an xlsx file, write the value in another cell and store the xlsx file.

I'm using the data_only mode

```
excelDoc = openpyxl.load_workbook(clientFile, data_only=True)
```

to read the formula value. But when I save the file all formulas are overriden by their values.

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can either have the values or the formulae.