# Openpyxl Keeping formulas but copying values

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

My workbook has 6 sheets.  The last 3 sheets are a bunch of formulas that I currently manually copy and paste values into the first 3 sheets.  I am using wb.copy_worksheet() to make the copies and loading the work book as data_only = True.  However, when I save, the formulas are all gone due to loading it as data_only.  Is there a way I can copy the values but keep the formulas?  The sheets are too large to go cell by cell.

Heres my code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("symbols.xlsx", data_only=True)

ws = wb.get_sheet_names()
print (ws)


Value = ws[0:3] #set equal to first 3 sheets


BB = ws[3:7] #set equal to last 3 sheets      

for s in range(0, len(Value)):

    CopyBB = wb.copy_worksheet(wb[BB[s]])  #copy from bb sheet
    CopyBB.title = Value[s]


myorder = [6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2]   #this is to reorder the sheets that got copied.

wb._sheets =[wb._sheets[i] for i in myorder]

wb.remove_sheet(wb.worksheets[8])
wb.remove_sheet(wb.worksheets[7])
wb.remove_sheet(wb.worksheets[6])

wb.worksheets[0].title = "Securities Values" 
wb.worksheets[1].title = "Indices Values"
wb.worksheets[2].title = "Currencies Values"


return wb.save("symbols.xlsx")
```

Comment: can you show us all the code, including the loading part?

Comment: Edited the original to show the full code.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000170/

Comment: Thanks Charlie.  Please close this question then.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. You have to use ='MVSM!A1', where MVSM is the sheetname then A1 is the cell value. Just use that when assigning cell value whilst using openpyxl.